# Fatal errors: Cannot redeclare class XXX

Tags: php, wordpress, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I used wordpress version 4.+ it hosted on IIS also use same pool from virtual directory . so this error periodically and also randomly occur on my blog.

I also search a lot and mentioned it maybe declared multiple function in several place but it isn't in my case. please advice me how can I resolve it?

Comment: Not sure how you expect others to help when you don't even give the error messages to indicate what classes are being redeclared and where.

Comment: @NigelRen as I mentioned on title it's randomly throw errors but most of type show me this erroe:
 `Fatal errors: Cannot redeclare class XXX` but when reset IIS pool every think work perfectly.